# Combobox selects the first item when searching for text

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, combobox

I have a combobox in which I can type in text and it suggests results based on list of items containing that text. Everything seems to be working fine, except when I type in the first letter, the combobox automatically selects the first item in the results list as can be seen in the screenshot (http://prntscr.com/pple6f). I need to press the key again to clear the text field and type in the proper name. Only then the results are correct (http://prntscr.com/pplekc)

I have the following method to check for combobox text update

```
 private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        listNew.Clear();
        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        foreach (var item in listOnit)
        {
            if (item.ToLower().Contains(this.comboBox1.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                listNew.Add(item);
            }
        }

        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(listNew.ToArray());
        comboBox1.SelectionStart = this.comboBox1.Text.Length;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

AutoCompleteMode is set to None, same with AutoCompleteSource.

I need the combobox to start filtering the results as soon as I start typing, not having to press the same letter twice. Are there any other options/properties that I need to check?

Comment: What is your data?

Comment: Can you use [AutoSuggestBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox )

Comment: Are there any other event handlers of your ComboBox?

Comment: According to the screenshot, this is in fact a WinForms question